# `#region ... implementation` of interfaces doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, interface

I tired to write Unit-Tests for a Unity3D project. There is this big issue with *MonoBehaviours*, making it quite hard. To solve that issue I used [this](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/06/03/unit-testing-part-2-unit-testing-monobehaviours/) tutorial to make a object construct called *Humble Object*.

In the tutorial has been this code (I simplified it):

```
public class Something : ISomething
{
  #region ISomething implementation

  void Test1() {
    // do something
  }

  #endregion

  void Test2() {
    Test1 ();
  }
}
```

As I get it, that should be equivalent to:

```
interface ISomething
{
  void Test1();
}

public class Something : ISomething
{
  public void Test1() {
    // do something
  }

  void Test2() {
    Test1 ();
  }
}
```

But if i write that first code and try to compile, I get this error message: (the second one does the job)

```
[...] The type or namespace name `ISomething' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to think that using `#region ISomething implementation` actually defines the interface.

It doesn't. [`#region`s have no effect on the code. They are just informational](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103434/region-descriptions-compiled-into-exe-in-net).

You have to actually define the interface as in your second example (and make it at least as accessible as the implementing class, in this case `public`).

Answer (score 2):

> As I get it, that should be equivalent to:

**NO**, it's not at all. You have to create the interface first and that's why it's throwing the said error. `Region` is just code markup for better redability purpose.